# how to make a two week cycle(the fisrt monday is day one and the second monday is day 6)

Tags: delphi, date

how do I make two week cycle. Monday to Friday... day 1 to day 5 and then(skipping the weekend) the following Monday to Friday... day 6 to day 10.

```
var
 datee : Tdatetime;
 time, date, dateDOW : String;
 dOW : array[1..14] of string;
 Form2: TForm2;

begin

  datee := now;
  date := DateTOStr(now);
  time := TimeTOStr(now);
  lbl_date.Caption := DateTOStr(now);
  lbl_time.Caption := TimeTOStr(now);
  dow[1] := 'Monday';
  dow[2] := 'Tuesday';
  dow[3] := 'Wednesday';
  dow[4] := 'Thursday';
  dow[5] := 'Friday';
  dow[6] := 'Saturday';
  dow[7] := 'Sunday';
  dow[8] := 'Monday';
  dow[9] := 'Tuesday';
  dow[10] := 'Wednesday';
  dow[11] := 'Thursday';
  dow[12] := 'Friday';
  dow[13] := 'Saturday';
  dow[14] := 'Sunday';
  datee := encodedate(strToint(edt_date1.text), strtoint(edt_date2.text), strtoint(edt_date3.text));
  dateDOW := dow[DayOfWeek(datee - 1)];
  lbl_DOW.Caption := dateDOW;
end;
```

I want it to be like when it is '3 march 2014' the day = 1. and when '10 match 2014' the day = 6. and then '17 march 2014' the day = 1.

those are the specific values each of those dates must have. how can I start the cycle?
the 'day' goes from 1..10(the weekends are not included)
Friday =5, Monday =6

Comment: Something [`like this`](http://pastebin.com/U6y3HbY2) ?

Comment: the condition, yes. but that only solves the problem to look for Monday to Friday.

Comment: Sorry, then I don't understand your question.

Comment: I've no idea what that question is. I mean, if you want to skip the weekend, skip the weekend.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think he wants an infinite iterator that runs 1-5,5,5,6-10,10,10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to know what you're looking for. 
Try this:

```
function GerhardiTecDayOfWeek ( nDate : tDateTime ) : integer;
const
  Map : array [ 0 .. 13 ] of integer = (5,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,1,2,3,4,5);
begin
  Result := Map [ trunc(nDate) mod 14 ];
end;
```

Here are the results of calling this function with various dates:

```
                Date     Divide 14     Map
   Date      as Number   Remainder    Result
-----------    -----        --          --
03-Mar-2014    41701         9           1
04-Mar-2014    41702        10           2
05-Mar-2014    41703        11           3
06-Mar-2014    41704        12           4
07-Mar-2014    41705        13           5
08-Mar-2014    41706         0           5
09-Mar-2014    41707         1           5
10-Mar-2014    41708         2           6
11-Mar-2014    41709         3           7
12-Mar-2014    41710         4           8
13-Mar-2014    41711         5           9
14-Mar-2014    41712         6          10
15-Mar-2014    41713         7          10
16-Mar-2014    41714         8          10
17-Mar-2014    41715         9           1
18-Mar-2014    41716        10           2
19-Mar-2014    41717        11           3
20-Mar-2014    41718        12           4
21-Mar-2014    41719        13           5
22-Mar-2014    41720         0           5
23-Mar-2014    41721         1           5
24-Mar-2014    41722         2           6
25-Mar-2014    41723         3           7
26-Mar-2014    41724         4           8
27-Mar-2014    41725         5           9
28-Mar-2014    41726         6          10
29-Mar-2014    41727         7          10
30-Mar-2014    41728         8          10
31-Mar-2014    41729         9           1
01-Apr-2014    41730        10           2
```

Dates are simply stored as floating point numbers.  The integer portion is the number of days from a fixed date. (30-Dec-1899) The fractional part is the time of day.  Here we are just using dates, we can ignore the time part.   Calling `trunc` converts the value to integer type.  `Mod 14` means divide by 14 and keep the remainder.  So you get a number from zero to 13.  You said that 03-Mar-2014 should be day #1.  That date is represented as 40701. Divide that by 14 and you get a remainder of 9.  So we set the value of Map[9] to be 1. The day after that is 2. The day after that is 3. Then 4 and 5.  Now we wrap around. Saturday, 08-Mar-2014 is number 41706. Divide that by 14, and the remainder is zero.  So we set Map[0] to the value for Saturday.  I assumed you'd want to return 5 for Saturday and Sunday.  The next Monday, 10-Mar-2014 is 41708. Divide that by 14, the remainder is 2. So we set Map[2] to be 6. Next Tuesday is Map[3], so that's 7, and so on. Finally you get to the following Monday, 17-Mar-2014. That's 41715 divided by 14, with a reminder of 9. And we've wrapped around back to the beginning, with Map[9] set to one.

Note, as written, the routine will only work with dates after 30-Dec-1899.  If you need to deal with dates before that `MOD` will return a negative value.  The routine could be modified to work with those dates if necessary.

Comment: I have no idea how this Is working! but it does! thank you :) can you please explain it to me?

Comment: I've added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If your period always starts with Monday:

```
var
  FirstDay, DayDate: TDateTime;
  AWeek, ADay, DayNum: Integer;
begin
  FirstDay := StartOfTheWeek(Now);
  for AWeek := 0 to 1 do
    for ADay := 1 to 5 do begin
       DayNum := AWeek * 5 + ADay;
       DayDate := FirstDay + AWeek * 7 + ADay;
       Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(DayNum) + ': ' + DateToStr(DayDate));
    end;


1: 25.02.2014
2: 26.02.2014
3: 27.02.2014
4: 28.02.2014
5: 01.03.2014
6: 04.03.2014
7: 05.03.2014
8: 06.03.2014
9: 07.03.2014
10: 08.03.2014
```

Comment: can you please explain how I can interpret this into date? a start point(3 march 2014 ---- day = 1). and if I type in any date(not weekend dates) if will give me the day = ▲.

Comment: @GerhardiTec I expanded example

Comment: "FirstDay := StartOfTheWeek(Now);" the startoftheweek is unrecognized. what can I replace it with?

Comment: This function is from DateUtils unit (in XE3). You may want to use another method for start day (I did not understand all condtitions - how to choose it)